# How to re-render only specific data on radio button change JS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I'm fairly new to AJAX. I have a `data.json` file from which I am retrieving an array of objects. Each object has a `time` key. It looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "time": 3
    },
    {
        "time": 35
    }
]
```

Now, I have two radio buttons from bootstrap. One says "Minutes" and one says "Seconds". I would like to show the time from that `data.json` in minutes by default, and then when the user changes to "Seconds" it gets re-rendered without refreshing the page. I've been working with things like this in React but I'm not sure how to do it with vanilla JS and AJAX.

My `<body>` looks like this:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Minutes 
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Seconds
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="render-here">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const container = document.getElementById('render-here');

        function renderPrice(time) {
            return `<span class="price-currency-char"></span><span class="price-value">${time}</span>`;;
        }   

        xhr.onload = function() {
            const res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                let item = res[i];
                container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `                    
                    ${renderPrice(item.time)}<br/>
                `)                
            }
        };

        xhr.open('get', 'data.json');

        xhr.send();
    </script>
```

So in the AJAX `onload` function, I get the data and dynamically render it with a for loop.

I hope I explained everything well and gave all the necessary information. Please let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use fetch as it is easier to work with. With fetch, you first use the `.json()` method to interpret the source as JSON and then work with that data. Because it is an array, I found it easier to use the `.forEach()` method here to allow me to execute the entire fun action in one line.

For the sake of example, I uploaded your sample array data to PasteBin to pull from with my fetch so you can see it in action. This should work:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('render-here');
const renderPrice = time => `<span class="price-currency-char"></span><span class="price-value">${time}</span>`;

const calculate = () => {
  container.innerHTML = "";
  const multiplier = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').dataset.multipler);
  fetch('https://pastebin.com/raw/PBkVKmsQ').then(response => response.json()).then(data => data.forEach(item => container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${renderPrice(item.time * multiplier)}<br/>`)));
};
calculate();
document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target?.matches('input[name="options"]')) calculate();
})
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" data-multipler="1" checked> Minutes 
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" data-multipler="60"> Seconds
    </label>
</div>

<div id="render-here"></div>
```

Comment: The fetch thing is cool thanks. But this doesn't solve the main issue in which data gets re-rendered when I select "Minutes" or "Seconds".

Comment: @crodev could you clarify that a bit? In my example, the data does not get re-rendered/re-fetched when you select minutes/seconds. Do you want it to each time a different option is selected?

Comment: Sorry, I should've gone into more detail. So, the value in the `time` key in the objects is time in minutes. So when I press the "Seconds" button I want the values to rerender to be `time*60`, because that's the time in seconds. And when I click "Minutes" again, it should go back to just `time`. And all that must happen without the page refreshing.

Comment: @crodev no worries. I've added this to my example. I made to use a data-attribute here, but the multiplier value could be moved entirely into the JS if you don't have to include the multiplier in the HTML. Instead of getting the value from the attribute, you would just do a ternary check for `multiplier = document.querySelector('#option2:checked') ? 60 : 1;`

Comment: This looks great! Thank you! I'll check it out later today/tomorrow and see if it works!